# List<Uri> How do I get at its contents?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I've got the following class that uses the HtmlAgilityPack to create a list of uri's from  the current page/document.

```
public List<Uri> getLinks() 
{
    var linksOnPage = from lnks in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                      where lnks.Name == "a" &&
                           lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
                           lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                      select new
                          {
                              Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                          };

    List<Uri> Uris = new List<Uri>();

    foreach (var link in linksOnPage)
    {
        Uri baseUri = new Uri(urlBase, UriKind.Absolute);
        Uri page = new Uri(baseUri, link.Url.ToString());
        Uris.Add(page);
    }

    return Uris;
}
```

**So, I have the following questions:**

1. How do I get the first item in the list when calling this class from elsewhere in my code? - Answered.
2. How do I loop through all the uris in the list should I wish to write them out for example, when calling this from elsewhere in my code? - Answered
3. How can I adapt this so that it reads the uris from an input string rather than the whole document?

Comment: `How do I loop through all the uris in the list` How did you write the linq in the question while you don't know how to a loop?

Comment: I meant externally to this. So when the above returns its List<>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the much easier way to acheive my goal is:

```
matchString = Regex.Match(((Property)e.Item.FindControl("Property4")).Text, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;//image src
```

Comment: In that case, you should accept your own answer. Visitors should see what's the best answer to your question.

Comment: Linus, I have to wait two days to answer my own question. But, yes, that is why I posted my answer so that it could act as a reference for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first item of the list:

```
var first = getLinks().FirstOrDefault(); // null if the list is empty
```

Loop through:

```
foreach (var uri in getLinks())
{
    // do the job
}
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the response. But, I meant in relation to the List<> returned by the above class. Would it be as a simple as: var first = getLinks().FirstOrDefault() ???

Comment: Thanks Linus! Its really appreciated. I realise it might be a dumb question but its only obvious when you actually know the answer. ;-))